# Create new Pandas DataFrame based on existing DataFrame and conditional operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new DataFrame based on values from an existing DataFrame

**Source DataFrame**

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'y': ['1', '---', '1', '1', '1']})

    x   y
0   1   1
1   2   ---
2   3   1
3   4   1
4   5   1
```

**Intended target DataFrame**

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'z': int(a['x']) + int(a['y']) if a['y'] != '---' else '---'})

    z
0   2
1   ---
2   4
3   5
4   6
```

I get a "***ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous***"

Does someone know and can give me a hint?

Comment: Why does your df have string value? Is it a design choice?

Comment: Yes, it's how I get data delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data frame was purely formed by by numbers an inline code like this `a.astype(int).sum(axis = 1)` would solve your problem.

But since you cannot guarantee that every row has numbers you have to iterate over the rows and do the calculation you need based on your condition. In the example below, I use the *apply* function along with lambda to reach de desired result.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
   z = a.apply(lambda r: int(r['x']) + int(r['y']) if r['y'] != '---' else '---' , axis=1 )
    )
)
```

To apply in the same DF check below:

```
a['z'] = a.apply(lambda r: int(r['x']) + int(r['y']) if r['y'] != '---' else '---' , axis=1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution grabs the index where `y!='---'` and then sums up values at `a['x']` & `a['y']` at that index. It is important to convert the dtype to `int` before summing.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'y': ['1', '---', '1', '1', '1']})
a['z'] = None

indexer = a['y'].loc[lambda x:x!='---'].index

a['z'] = a[a.index.isin(indexer)]['x'].astype(int) + a[a.index.isin(indexer)]['y'].astype(int)

a.loc[a['z'].isna(), 'z'] = '---'

b = a[['z']]

print(b)
#Output

    z
0   2
1   ---
2   4
3   5
4   6
```

This assumes that `'---'` is the only symbol in your dataset and wherever the condition is not met, the `z` values are `NaN`. These `NaN` values are then set to `---` in `a['z']`.